# Redirect rules in htaccess with trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following configuration on my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test_page(.*)$ https://www.testing.com/test_page/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

`https://www.testing.com/test_page/` is where route to my wordpress website.

When i tried `https://www.testing.com/test_page`, it will redirect me to `https://www.testing.com/test/public/test_page`, where test/public is my application located.

There must be a trailing slash to allow me route to my wordpress website.

How can make `https://www.testing.com/test_page` route to `https://www.testing.com/test_page/` with my current rule?

I expected

> Request URL: https://www.testing.com/test_page
>
> Location URL: https://www.testing.com/test_page/

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: There are things unclear in your question. Please take the time to revise your question (there is an `edit` link below it, _use it_ ) to make it more precise: 1. The set of rewriting rules you posted will result in an endless rewriting loop, unless other rules come into play too which you did not post. 2. it is unclear what you actually try to do, why should it make a difference whether you have a trainling slash internally? This will only make a difference again if you have other rules in place which you did not post. So most likely your question is incomplete.

Comment: @arkascha This is the rules where set in my htaccess. I have the issue when access to https://www.testing.com/test_page/ (wordpress site) using https://www.testing.com/test_page. There's must be a slash end of the url to access my wordpress website.

Comment: You did not answer at all to what I write. Why not? Just repeating what you already wrote makes little sense when it is pointed out to you that what you already wrote is unclear.